# Can i use a unique key as a foreign key?

Tags: database, oracle

every event i have should have one supervisor assigned to it, all supervisors have one account “username”,to filter the what event assigned to a supervisor i want to use sup_id “supervisor id”. Will that work? The event is a weak entity because it depends on the host to make hosting event request

Answer (score 0):

create a supervisor table having a foreign key as the supervisor id
must be unique

create an event table having a foreign key, supervisor id, linked to the supervisor table

create as many events as wished, each record having an unique event id, but the supervisor id repeated as many times

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a unique key as a foreign key try this

```
create table supervisor (
     supervisor_id number not null
        , supervisor_name varchar2 (30) not null
        , constraint supervisor_pk primary key ( supervisor_id )
        , constraint supervisor_uk unique ( supervisor_name )
        );

 drop table event;  

create table event (
       event_id number not null
        , supervisor_name
        , constraint event_pk primary key ( event_id )
        , constraint evt_supervisor_pk foreign key ( supervisor_name )
            references supervisor ( supervisor_name )
        );
```